# Porto blog generates sql error, any ideas?

Tags: sql, debugging, blog

I'm using smartwave magento theme. I can edit settings of blog, but I get the following error generated when I try and open blog categories or posts in backend.

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'my_database.mage_smartwave_blog' doesn't exist
```

Trace:

```
0 /home/namui/domains/namui.lt/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

1 /home/namui/domains/namui.lt/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)

2 /home/namui/domains/namui.lt/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)

.............
```

Answer (score 1):

Try asking the extension vendor. Maybe your extension was not installed properly. Please clear the caches and open the website again.

You can check whether update scripts with `n98-magerun.phar sys:setup:compare-versions`

n98-magerun: https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun